# What is the cheapest way to make a react website that searches a static, read-only database (e.g. movie search)?

Tags: reactjs, database, search, database-design, pouchdb

I want to integrate search into my website e.g. typing in a movie name, returning the data I have on that movie (could be about 20 different numbers or strings).

I don't care if people can somehow see the database. I just want that data to be returnable when someone searches for it. I DON'T want that data to ever be changed by a user. Let's say that the database is of around 50,000 movies.

I don't have many resources to run this website and server, so I would like to keep server costs down.

What would be the cheapest ways of running this kind of website? i.e. client-side search, server-side search, what hosting service?

I came across pouchdb and watermelondb, which provide an offline database. This would be quite nice if it's not too costly.

Any relevant tutorials or guides would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here. Also, StackOverflow is a site for specific programming questions and answers. It's not a discussion forum, so "asking about the cheapest way to make a website" is not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an infrastructure question than a React one, but given that your data and site aren't changing, there are some solid workarounds you could do to get cheap hosting.

Let's assume you're using `create-react-app`, so you can easily build into a static deployment.  You can put your site into an S3 bucket and then just pay when people GET things out of it, which would be quite cheap.

You'll want to keep your data someplace else; that way users can fetch your site quickly, then let the underlying data load separately.  You could put it into another S3 bucket, and bam, you've got a static site with a static data source -- all for cheap.  You wouldn't want to load the entire database at once, so maybe you:

1. Make a dedicated file which just has all the names, so the client can load that and then autocomplete any name available.
2. Group your data into separate files of a smaller size, in some way that you can immediately get the group you need.  The most basic answer would just be alphabetical chunks.

Note that S3 really isn't a database, it's just a place to permanently store data.  It doesn't do writes very well; this solution only works because your movie list isn't changing.

Here's a tutorial on hosting a React app through S3 to help get you started: https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-guide-to-deploying-your-react-app-with-aws-s3-including-https-a-custom-domain-a-cdn-and-58245251f081